# I'm trying to make a table print page in django but when I pass multiple value through dict it's print only first value

Tags: python, django, render

**views.py**

```
def inp(request):
    return render(request,'inp.html')
def tab(request):
    num1 = dict()
    number =int (request.GET.get('num'))
    for i in range(1,11):
        num1[i] = number*i
    for key in num1:
        print(num1[key])
        return render(request,'tab.html',{"result" : num1[key]})
```

**inp.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>table</title>
    </head>
    <h1>Enter The Number Which You Want For Table</h1> 
 <body>
  <form action ="tab/" method="get">
      Enter a Number:<input type = "text" name ="num">
      <input type = "submit">
</form>
 </body>   
</html>
```

**tab.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>output</title>
    </head>
 <body>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>
 your answer is {{result}}<br>


 </body>   
</html>`enter code here`

 - List item
```

Comment: Please provide a clear description of your issue.

Comment: because returned in for loop so on first return the program will return first value and stop execution.

Comment: any alternative

Comment: @TusharKhowal you want to print multiplication table right?

Comment: @ShubhamDevgan yes

Comment: @TusharKhowal I have written answer for your problem , you can try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modfiy the tab function

```
 def tab(request):
        num1 = dict()
        number =int (request.GET.get('num'))
        for i in range(1,11):
            num1[i] = number*i

        return render(request,'tab.html',{"result" : num1})
```

Modify the template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>output</title>
    </head>
 <body>
 {% for value in result.values %}
 your answer is {{value}}<br>
{% endfor %}

 </body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `views.py`

```
def inp(request):
    return render(request,'inp.html')
def tab(request):
    num1 = dict()
    number =int (request.GET.get('num'))
    for i in range(1,11):
        num1[i] = number*i

    return render(request,'tab.html',{"number":number,"result" : num1.values()})
```

in your `tab.html`  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>output</title>
    </head>
 <body>
{% for x in result %}
    {{number}} * {{ forloop.counter }} = {{x}}
{% endfor %}
 </body>   
</html>
```